# AMQP implementations with Celery

Tags: python, amqp, celery

I wanted to get your opinions on the merits of different AMQP implementations to be used with celery. I am looking particularly at message prioritization and job queue sizes. 
What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some docs and trying out a few options, I have found that RabbitMQ suffices for most purposes.

Comment: FWIW, RabbitMQ doesn't support message priorities, which seems to be one of your requirements.